# Getting user input text without HTML input elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way using angular or just javascript to get the user input text not using HTML input boxes? For example when a user clicks on a paragraph he will be able to change its text without a text area  popping so he could input. I tried focusing on angular ngHide element( a input  HTML) but with no success. It only focused on the element when its showing.

Comment: It is possible, but most likely is not a good idea. What is the problem with input fields?

Comment: Do the same with `input` field only and customize that using css and make a feel of normal paragraph instead of input

Comment: @SyamPillai auto height will not work on input not a good idea

Answer (score 2):

Try `contenteditable` introduced in HTML 5.

[Try Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/wcyt39d5/1/).

```
<p contenteditable="true" onfocus="alert(this.textContent)" onblur="alert(this.textContent)">
   Enter Name
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

But there is. [contenteditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content) is an HTML attribute that makes divs and cells editable. you can make a directive in angularjs to use that, but beware of the [caveats](https://medium.engineering/why-contenteditable-is-terrible-122d8a40e480#.rez59a7sg) that it introduces.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [x-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/). It will suit your needs, i think.